# Dynamic Pivot Not displaying right output

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic, pivot

I have this table:

```
Year Month| User| Player  | Manager
1996-06   | 1256|  2      |   1
1997-07   | 1243|  5      |   2
```

and was trying to pivot it so it returns:

```
       | 1997-06|1996-07
User   | 1256   | 1243
Player | 2      |   5
Manager| 1      |   2
```

however I'm not to sure why my script below is returning something different:

```
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @columns = N'';
SELECT @columns += N', p.' + QUOTENAME([User]) 
  FROM (SELECT p.[User] FROM dbo.practise AS p
  GROUP BY p.[User]) AS x;
SET @sql = N'
SELECT ' + STUFF(@columns, 1, 2, '') + '
FROM
(
  SELECT [year month], [User]
   FROM dbo.practise AS p

) AS j
PIVOT
(
  SUM([User]) FOR [year month] IN ('
  + STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', p.[', ',['), 1, 1, '')
  + ')
) AS p;';
PRINT @sql;
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

It returns:

```
    1256|1243
1   Null|Null
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your could simplify this a bit

**Example**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
Select *
 From  (
        Select [Year Month]
              ,B.*
         From practise
         Cross Apply (values (''User''   ,cast([User]  as varchar(max)))
                            ,(''Player'' ,cast(Player  as varchar(max)))
                            ,(''Manager'',cast(Manager as varchar(max)))
                     ) B (Item,Value)

       ) A
 Pivot (max([Value]) For [year month] in (' + Stuff((Select Distinct ','+QuoteName([year month]) 
                                                      From practise
                                                      Order By 1 
                                                      For XML Path('')),1,1,'')  + ') ) p
 Order by 1 Desc'
Exec(@SQL);
--Print @SQL
```

**Returns**

```
Item    1996-06   1997-07
User    1256      1243
Player  2         5
Manager 1         2
```

**The Generated SQL Looks Like This**

```
Select *
 From  (
        Select [Year Month]
              ,B.*
         From practise
         Cross Apply (values ('User'   ,cast([User]  as varchar(max)))
                            ,('Player' ,cast(Player  as varchar(max)))
                            ,('Manager',cast(Manager as varchar(max)))
                     ) B (Item,Value)

       ) A
 Pivot (max([Value]) For [year month] in ([1996-06],[1997-07]) ) p
 Order by 1 Desc
```

Comment: Hi john cappelletti    ...in the pivot (max([user] for [year month] in etc etc statement
Can there be more that one extract for (max([user]
e.g.    pivot (max([user]), (max([player]), (max([manager]) for [year month] in (' + stuff...

Or would i have to create a new pivot everytime i wanted to transpose a new column to a row?

Comment: @VS1SQL Perhaps you could edit your question and provide a better sample data.

Comment: @VS1SQL To answer your question, Yes, we would need to UNPIVOT the data within the dynamic Pivot.  Again, a more robust data sample and desired results would be most helpful

Comment: Apologies, I have amended the sample data and desired results as an example @John Cappelletti

Comment: @VS1SQL One moment

Comment: @VS1SQL See Updated Answer

Comment: Ahh,  I see, essentially using cross apply rather than inner join for the pivoting. interesting. Thanks for this insight and Answer! @john Cappelletti

Comment: @VS1SQL Happy to help